# Find out where $PATH is defined

Tags: find, path, arch-linux, bashrc

I recently installed an Arch-Linux System. If I type

```
echo $PATH
```

it points (among others) to a directory inside my `/home/user/dir` I can remember I set up somewhere. I have it as root user also, so it cannot be in `~/.bashrc` and isn't as well in `/root/.bashrc`. I looked also inside `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bash.bashrc` but couldn't find it there, too.

Is there a way to find where it is set?

Comment: How are you logging in as `root` to get the same `PATH`? Even if you log in from the console, inheriting nothing from another user session?

Comment: yes, even if I log in via `tty1` as root or at run-level 3. I guess theres no user-session inside run-level 3?!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try searching for the directory in all files in `/etc`:

```
sudo grep -r "/home/user/dir" /etc
```

The `-r` switch makes `grep` search for `/home/user/dir` in the *contents* of all files in `/etc` and its subdirectories.

From [grep(1) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep):

> **-d** ACTION, **--directories**=ACTION
>
> > If an input file is a directory, use ACTION to process it. By default, ACTION is **read**, which means that directories are read just as if they were ordinary files. If ACTION is **skip**, directories are silently skipped. If ACTION is **recurse**, grep reads all files under each directory, recursively; this is equivalent to the **-r** option.

If that fails, you could simply extend the search to **all** files:

```
sudo grep -r "/home/user/dir" /
```

Or you could search for all files that modify the `PATH` variable:

```
sudo grep -r "PATH=" /
```

Answer (score 1):

It's usually a bad idea to put user directories in the global path as root ;) Did you check the `/etc/environment` file?

Comment: no, but did it now, and still no luck

Answer (score 0):

@Dennis points me to a nice idea! I searched inside my `/etc` and found it, but with another command, as his command is only searching for filenames (as far as I understand).

The one I used succesful was

```
find / -type f -exec grep -i /home/user/dir '{}' \; -print
```

Comment: My command would have worked as well. The only difference is the `-i` switch, which should be unnecessary since the path is case sensitive. `grep -r` recursively searches the **contents** of all files in the specified folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you're deep fishing for where something is defined in your PATH you might try this alternative using [the silver searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) for fast searching.

By default it outputs matches with line numbers, so combine with `egrep` to get only output of filenames. It will also output line numbers containing matches so `cut` to isolate filenames and `uniq` if you don't want duplicates. Of course any of the piped commands can be omitted if you wan't full output of matches.

```
ag -s '/home/user/dir' | egrep '^\d+' | cut -d ':' -f 1 | uniq
```