# How do I find out where paths in my $PATH were defined?

Tags: bash, osx-lion, path

There are some paths in $PATH, which I don't want. I'm not sure how they got there; they aren't coming from my `.profile`. Is there a way to determine which scripts are modifying $PATH?

Comment: Related: [Find out where $PATH is defined](http://superuser.com/q/443704)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very first file to processed is `/etc/profile`. At the beginning of this file, add the line

```
set -x
```

then open a new terminal window. You will get more output than you wanted, but it will be a trace of all the bash code that is executed from your startup scripts.

Comment: Nothing happens. What is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 4):

In OS X, default paths are set in `/etc/paths`, and possibly in the sub-files (if any) of `/etc/paths.d/`. See also `path_helper(8)`.

Comment: The accepted answer (about `set x`) did give me "all the bash code that [was] executed from [my] startup scripts," but it didn't tell me *which* startup script executed each bit of code. The incorrect behavior I was looking for was caused by a file in `/etc/paths.d/`.